# Implementing C++ equivalent of C# using statement

Tags: c#, c++, templates, using-statement

I am looking for an elegant solution for implementing the equivalent of the C# using statement in C++. Ideally the resultant syntax should be simple to use and read.

C# Using statement details are here - 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=vs.80).aspx

I am not sure whether the solution would be to use function pointers with destructors on classes, some form of clever template programming or even meta template programming. Basically I do not know where to start with this...

Comment: I've been told RAII covers this.

Comment: As Anthony said, using RAII will automatically do this for you, and imho, it makes the code far cleaner than the using pattern.

Comment: From my point of view, the `using` keyword is just a mediocre remedy for not having RAII in the first place. So, thou shalt not seek to emulate it.

Comment: @Andre It is a little bit harder. I suppose that the C# compiler could treat a scoped IDisposable similar to RAII, but I am not sure how it would know that it is safe to dispose the object. Maybe check the ref count when the object leaves scope and immediately call dispose if 0?

Comment: @Mranz What are you talking about? Dispose is guaranteed to be called when the `using` scope ends. Read all about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am talking about not having to use the using scope.

Comment: The `using` keyword is error prone and has been added to C# as an afterthought. It is very easy to write wrong code by forgetting it. C++ has a better mechanism which does not require you to write anything: destructors !

Comment: @mranz I see. That's not going to fly at all. Also .net gc does not use ref counts.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right, it walks the stack. Either way, I think they can do better.

Comment: @alex perhaps you don't recognise the different motivations with gc

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I do recognize that nondeterministic destruction of objects makes it hard to bind events to destruction time. However, the `using` keyword and the `IDisposable` interface *are* error prone. Forget to write `using` (you won't get even a warning) and all can go wrong. Garbage collected functional languages like Scheme have proper RAII (eg. `call-with-port`).

Comment: @AlexandreC. Surely it's possible to forget to use call-with-port? Or is there something extra. Surely you need to somehow tell the environment about unmanaged resources so they can be treated specially.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You don't need to implement this in C++ because the standard pattern of RAII already does what you need.

```
{
    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("hello.txt");
    myfile << "Hello\n";
}
```

When the block scope ends, `myfile` is destroyed which closes the file and frees any resources associated with the object.

The reason the `using` statement exists in C# is to provide some syntactic sugar around try/finally and `IDisposable`. It is simply not needed in C++ because the two languages differ and the problem is solved differently in each language.

Comment: This is far superior to the C# `using`, and it also works with .NET objects in C++/CLI.  The C++ syntax is far better because although you still have to remember to use the value semantics syntax: (1) You can use it for every type, whether or not it implements `IDisposable`, or not, or for interfaces, different objects may or may not, and (2) It works for class members.

Comment: I think it's not a matter of better or worse, it's a matter of what tools you have to deal with the problem in your environment. C++ uses heap as memory management and also stack, but it doesn't have garbage collection, so that's the difference, GC delayed memory management, which has it's own advantages, so what should I do to work in that context? we're not different sport teams here, we're developers dealing with different technologies...

Comment: I don't see how this is the accepted answer, and by so many up-votes, since RAII is just a design principal. Isn't it setting yourself up for failure to say that RAII takes care of everything, all the time? The better answer and more analogous to C#'s `using` statement seems to be [Smart Pointer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx) usage, more specifically, [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) as mentioned by another answer here. The smart pointer implements a RAII wrapper for you on the calling side of allocation, so analogous to `using`.

Comment: As an alternative that emphasizes your RAII object better: `if(std::ofstream myfile("hello.txt"); true) { /* code */ };`. You can see how if you put it on multiple lines, the object is put apart from the code inside the curly braces, same as in C#: `using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("hello.txt")) { // code }`.

Answer (score 3):

I'd take a look at using std::auto_ptr<> to handle cleanup of any instances allocated and assigned to a pointer within a particular scope -- otherwise, any variables declared within a specific scope will simply be destructed when exiting said scope.

```
{
    SomeClass A;
    A.doSomething();
} // The destructor for A gets called after exiting this scope here

{
    SomeClass* pA = new SomeClass();
    std::auto_ptr<SomeClass> pAutoA(pA);
    pAutoA->doSomething();
} // The destructor for A also gets called here, but only because we
  // declared a std::auto_ptr<> and assigned A to it within the scope.
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auto_ptr for a little more information on std::auto_ptr<>

Comment: Good to know, thanks.  Most days, I usually stick to the Boost libraries anyways...

Comment: There are other [Smart Pointers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh279674.aspx), in addition to auto_ptr and unique_ptr.

Answer (score 3):

A more verbose RAII pattern that resembles C#'s using statement can be accomplished with a simple macro.

```
#define Using(what, body) { what; body; }

Using(int a=9,
{
    a++;
})

a++; // compile error, a has gone out of scope here
```

Note we must use a capital "Using" to avoid a collision with C++'s built in "using" statement which obviously has a different meaning.

Comment: I like this becasue I like the explicit nature of 'using'. As for the macro itself, I like this one better: https://tedclancy.wordpress.com/2015/07/04/raii-helper-macro/.

Answer (score 3):

First, we have to define a Closeable/Disposable public interface:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class Disposable{
private:
    int disposed=0;
public:
    int notDisposed(){
        return !disposed;
    }
    
    void doDispose(){
        disposed = true;
        dispose();
    }
    
    virtual void dispose(){}
    
};
```

Then we should define a macro for the using keyword:

```
#define using(obj) for(Disposable *__tmpPtr=obj;__tmpPtr->notDisposed();__tmpPtr->doDispose())
```

and; here is an example application:

```
class Connection : public Disposable {
    
private:
    Connection *previous=nullptr;
public:
    static Connection *instance;
    
    Connection(){
        previous=instance;
        instance=this;
    }
    
    void dispose(){
        delete instance;
        instance = previous;
    }
};

Connection *Connection::instance = nullptr;

int Execute(const char* query){
    if(Connection::instance == nullptr){
        cout << "------- No Connection -------" << endl;
        cout << query << endl;
        cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        
        return -1;//throw some Exception
    }
    
    cout << "------ Execution Result ------" << endl;
    cout << query << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    
    using(new Connection())
    {
        Execute("SELECT King FROM goats");//in the scope 
    }
    
    Execute("SELECT * FROM goats");//out of the scope
    
}
```

But if you want to delete variables automatically from memory, you can simply use braces `{}`; therefore, every variable inside of the scope will be removed at the end of the scope.
here is an example:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    {
        int i=23;
    } 
    
    // the variable i has been deleted from the momery at here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    #define USING(...) if(__VA_ARGS__; true)

        USING(int i = 0)
        USING(std::string s = "0")
        {
            Assert::IsTrue(i == 0, L"Invalid result", LINE_INFO());
            Assert::IsTrue(s == "0", L"Invalid result", LINE_INFO());
        }
        //i = 1; // error C2065: 'i': undeclared identifier
        //s = "1"; //error C2065: 's': undeclared identifier
```

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend reading the following links:

1. [C++ RAII compared with Java Dispose pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/hsutter/archive/2004/07/31/203137.aspx)
2. [Constructor Exceptions in C++, C#, and Java](http://herbsutter.com/2008/07/25/constructor-exceptions-in-c-c-and-java/)
3. [More C++ Idioms/Resource Acquisition Is Initialization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C++_Idioms/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)
4. [Resource Acquisition Is Initialization (RAII)](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C++_Programming/RAII)

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to other answers that emphasizes your RAII object, doesn't require macros and has a very similar syntax to C#:

```
if(std::ofstream myfile("hello.txt"); true) {
    // code 
};
```

The object is put apart from the code inside the curly braces, same as in C#:

```
using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("hello.txt")) {
    // code 
}
```

A separate keyword like in C#, instead of `if` would be better, of course.

With a macro, similar to C# syntax:

```
#define Using(what) if(what; true)

Using(std::ofstream myfile("hello.txt")) {
        // code 
};
```

Requires C++ 17.